# How to use FK/PK in Json file - Pentaho

Tags: json, pentaho, pdi

I'm new in Pentaho world and I m stuck with something.

Basically I have a json file and I want to save all the data into a Database. 
The json structure are like this:

[]PRIMARY

```
  {} 0
     FIELD1
     FIELD2
     FIELD3
     []SECONDARY
          {} 0
               []SECONDARY
                   {} 0
                        FIELD4
                        FIELD5
                        FIELD6
                   {} 1
                        FIELD7
                        FIELD8
                        FIELD9
     []THIRD
          {} 0
               []FOURTH
                     {} 0
                          FIELD10
                          FIELD11
                          FIELD12
                     {} 1
                          FIELD13
                          FIELD14
                          FIELD15
```

I have the ideia to break in three tables. PRIMARY, SECONDARY and THIRD. I thought that i need to make a idPrimary as PK, them put a idPrimary_FK in both, seconday and third. But how can i do this?
 When i use a json file input, and select all the fields who belong to fourth, i can't put a FIELD1 in the same table, give me a error:

2015/12/20 00:12:57 - PRICES.0 - The data structure is not the same inside the resource! We found 65 values for json path [$.PRIMARY[*].FIELD1], which is different that the number returned for path [$.PRIMARY[*].SENCODARY[*].SENCODARY[*].FIELD4] (174 values). We MUST have the same number of values for all paths.

Please, help me guys.

Comment: If you suply the JSON as JSON it's easier to help you.

Comment: I can't. Its a json from work. Its confidential.

Comment: If you include your structure as JSON here, instead of some parsed structure, in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

The Pentaho JSON Input needs all the values to be present in equal amount. To solve the JSON parsing of this structure you need to use three different JSON steps.

Comment: I just tried: input json ( $.PRIMARY[].FIELD1,$.PRIMARY[].FIELD2,$.PRIMARY[].FIELD3) -> select values -> input json ($.PRIMARY[].SENCODARY[].SENCODARY[].FIELD4, $.PRIMARY[].SENCODARY[].SENCODARY[].FIELD5, $.PRIMARY[].SENCODARY[].SENCODARY[].FIELD6) -> select values -> input json ($.PRIMARY[].THIRD[].FOURTH[].FIELD4) -> SELECT VALUES.
And still don't workd. Do you have a example of three diferente json steps?

Comment: If you post your correct JSON I will give you a working example.